# For Loop inside API route... is this allowed? Not working here

Tags: javascript

I have an API call, that creates records in multiple tables using and inserting the same id as a foreign key in all of them at the same time.  I have made the code below, which in my mind would loop through the correct query for each table to create what I need.

```
const auditTables = ['audit_general', 'audit_culture', 
'audit_performance', 'audit_policies', 'audit_risk', 'audit_strategy', 
'audit_rewards', 'audit_workforce'];



app.put("/interview/create/questions/:lastEmployeeId", function (req, res) {
  console.log("It is getting to the route");
  const employee_id = req.body.lastEmployeeId;
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    for (i = 0; i < auditTables.length; i++) {
      connection.query(
        `INSERT INTO ${auditTables[i]} (employee_id) VALUES (?)`,
        [employee_id],
        function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          res.json(results);
          console.log(`Interview for ${auditTable[i]} has been created.`);
        }
      )
    };
    connection.release();
    })
});
```

However when I try running it, it crashes the server. But when I use this route instead, to add to just one of the tables, it works perfectly.  The only different is the loop. Can I just not do a loop and need to actually write out all 8 queries?

This one works:

```
app.put("/interview/create/questions/:lastEmployeeId", function (req, res) {
  console.log("It is getting to the route");
  const employee_id = req.body.lastEmployeeId;
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query(
      `INSERT INTO audit_general (employee_id)
            VALUES (?)`,
      [employee_id],
      function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(results);
        console.log(`Interview has been created`);
      }
    );
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

Comment: the error states `Cannot GET` ... but the endpoint is a `app.put` PUT -nothing to do with the for loop as such (though, there are issues with that code)

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand why the GET error.... when I run this code without the loop , it works as expected.

Comment: As I said, the loop is wrong, since it's going to do multiple asynchronous tasks inside all at once - perhaps that's the issue - perhaps you need to do each query after the previous ends - or maybe because it's calling res.json multiple times?

Comment: see if either of these work for you https://pastebin.com/t665BWpj - first does the queries one at a time, second does them in parallel (like your code would) except it only calls `res.json` ONCE

Answer (score 0):

`for (i = 0; i < auditTables.length; i++)`

Shouldn't that have a VAR in there?

`for (var i = 0; i < auditTables.length; i++)`